# Estimating nlp neural net training data set size

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, neural-network

I'm working on a simple question / answer solution where answers are returned given a question. I don't have a training set of question, answer pairs. I plan to take a subset of the data , approx 10 sentences and manually create 100 question answer pairs. How can I estimate how many questions / answer pairs will be required in order to answer questions from this data ?

Comment: Question Answering is a very well studied problem in NLP. Have you looked through the existing datasets and methods ?

Comment: @Prophecies I considered gate : https://gate.ac.uk/2mins.html but my understanding is that this is not a solved problem.

Comment: I meant more along the lines of [this](https://research.facebook.com/publications/large-scale-simple-question-answering-with-memory-networks/). No, QA is far from solved in its fullness but for the baBi dataset (the one I linked), the performances are getting near perfect for many categories.

Comment: @Prophecies thanks for link. I'm aware of that Facebook paper and the results are impressive but the required detail to implement is not provided ? What is the neural net architecture for this model ? Has it been open sourced, if not how can I implement this paper without more knowledge how the neural net is implemented ?